# Issue in using Tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

i am using TabbarController with four tabbarItem. but my requirement is Tabbar is shown in Top on viewController so that is done.but issue is when adding dropdownview on viewcontroller Tabbar hides dropdown. please help me

[image]

My viewController Class Code

```
   import UIKit

  class TrendingVC: UIViewController,DropDownViewDelegate
 {
   @IBOutlet var btndropdown: UIButton!
   var dropdown = DropDownView()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 dropdown = dropdown.initWithArrayData(["1111111111","222222222","3233333333","33333333333","1222333333"], cHeight: 30, tableviewHight: 150, tPaddingTop:0, tPaddingLeft: 0, tPaddingRight: 0, refView: btndropdown, tAnimation:AnimationType.GROW, openAnimationDuration: 0.5, closeAnimationDuration: 0.5, Dropdowncolor: UIColor.purpleColor(), DropdowntextColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), DropdowntextSize: 17) as! DropDownView

    dropdown.delegate = self;

    self.view.addSubview(dropdown.view);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func DropDownCellSelected(index: NSInteger)
{
    print(index);
}
@IBAction func btndropdownclik(sender:UIButton!)
{
     self.view.bringSubviewToFront(dropdown.view)
    dropdown.OpenAnimation()

}
```

My Custom Dropdown Class Code Here
     import UIKit

```
 enum AnimationType
 {
   case  BLENDIN
   case  GROW
   case  BOTH
  }
   protocol DropDownViewDelegate
   {
      func DropDownCellSelected(index:NSInteger) -> Void
   }
   class DropDownView:          UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
   {
   var arrDropDown = NSMutableArray()
   var delegate: DropDownViewDelegate!
   var OPENAnimationDuration,CLOSEAnimationDuration,DropdownViewTextsize,CellHight,DropDownHight,LeftMargin,RightMargin,TopMargin:CGFloat!
var refillview:UIView!
var DropdownViewColor,DropDownviewTextcolor:UIColor!
var animationType:AnimationType!
var tbl:UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let refFrame:CGRect = refillview.frame;

    tbl = UITableView();
    tbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, refFrame.size.width+RightMargin, (animationType == AnimationType.BOTH||animationType == AnimationType.BLENDIN) ?DropDownHight:1)
    tbl.dataSource = self;

    tbl.delegate = self;
    //uiTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:15/255 green:41/255 blue:63/255 alpha:1];
    tbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.view.addSubview(tbl)
    self.view.hidden = true;
    if (animationType == AnimationType.BOTH || animationType == AnimationType.BOTH)
    {
        self.view.alpha = 1;
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Tableview Methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrDropDown.count;
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellidentifier:NSString = "CellId";
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier as String)
    if  cell==nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellidentifier as String)
    }
    cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor();
    cell!.textLabel?.text = arrDropDown.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
    cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"helvetica" , size: 20)

    return cell!
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{

    return CellHight;
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.CloseAnimation()
    delegate.DropDownCellSelected(indexPath.row)

}
func OpenAnimation()
{
    self.view.hidden = false

    //var newCenter:CGPoint = CGPointMake(playAgainButton.center.x, playAgainButton.center.y + 200)
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
    tbl.frame = CGRectMake(tbl.frame.origin.x,tbl.frame.origin.y,tbl.frame.size.width, DropDownHight);
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}
func CloseAnimation()
{
    self.view.hidden = false;

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
    tbl.frame = CGRectMake(tbl.frame.origin.x,tbl.frame.origin.y,tbl.frame.size.width, 0);
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
func OpenAnimationWithRef()
{


}
func initWithArrayData(data:NSArray,cHeight:CGFloat,tableviewHight:CGFloat,tPaddingTop:CGFloat,tPaddingLeft:CGFloat,tPaddingRight:CGFloat,refView:UIView!,tAnimation:AnimationType,openAnimationDuration:CGFloat,closeAnimationDuration:CGFloat,Dropdowncolor:UIColor!,DropdowntextColor:UIColor!,DropdowntextSize:CGFloat) -> AnyObject
{
        arrDropDown=data.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray;
        CellHight = cHeight;
        DropDownHight = tableviewHight;
        TopMargin = tPaddingTop;
        LeftMargin = tPaddingLeft;
        RightMargin = tPaddingRight;
        refillview = refView;
        OPENAnimationDuration = openAnimationDuration;
        CLOSEAnimationDuration = closeAnimationDuration;
        animationType = tAnimation;
        DropdownViewColor = Dropdowncolor;
        DropDownviewTextcolor = DropdowntextColor;
        DropdownViewTextsize = DropdowntextSize;

    let reframe = refView.frame;
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(reframe.origin.x-LeftMargin, reframe.origin.y+reframe.size.height+TopMargin, reframe.size.width+RightMargin,DropDownHight);
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    tbl.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    tbl.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    tbl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor;
    tbl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
        return self
    }


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the line of code where you are setting the frame for dropdown view ? So that one can help even better.

Comment: Instead of "self.view.addSubview(dropdown.view);" try self.view.window.addSubview(dropdown.view);

Comment: @Bharath DropDown not display using these code

Comment: Have you tried the above code ? May I know what happened ?

Comment: @Bharath dropdownview not shown in my viewController

Comment: what are you using for tabbarcontroller storyboard or have you created it programmatically?...

Comment: @sanman borate  i using Tabbarcontroller in storyboard

Comment: @kajal If it's not necessary you can create custom view as tabbar. And using that it will be much easier for you to handle things. As far as your frame concerns that is correct as you have taken y position + button height + 64. You need to get y position of tab bar and height as well. and based on that you need to set frame of your dropdown.

Comment: you can try sending notification to tabbar controller on button press and add dragdown as subview on tabbarcontrollerview instead.because only two views are contained in tabbar controller view 1.UITransitionView and 2.UITabbar in that order.UITransitionView handles all viewcontroller transitions and your tabbar is covering UITransitionView which is host for all viewcontroller views  thats why your dragdown is being covered by tabbar.Hope this helps